# SQL: Math operation on values from the same column in the same table

Tags: sql

I need to substract population in 2000 from population in 2020 from each other:

```
country year population
USA     2000 281710000
USA     2020 331756000
...
```

How can i do that? Thank you

Comment: What's the expected result if one of the years are missing for a country?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join`:

```
select t2000.country, t2020.population - t2000.population
from t t2000 join
     t t2020
     on t2000.country = t2020.country
where t2000.year = 2000 and t2020.year = 2020;
```